# Android windowBackground turns with device

Tags: android, background

I have an androidapp with a background but I want to stay it in portrait always. So the activity can rotate, just the wallpaper can't. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this through code or through using the native behaviour of how landscape and portrait layout xml files are chosen based on the screen rotation.

In you res/ folder you by default have the layout/ folder. In here for example you might have main.xml with the background of your element set to @drawable/background_portrait.

What you can then do is create a new folder in the res/ folder called layout-land/ and within here you will also have main.xml

In the latter instance you should update the main.xml (In the layout-land/) folder to specify the background as @drawable/background_landscape.

You can then customise each background image as required. The Device will display the main.xml file based on the current orientation.

**Through Code**
In Code, in the onCreate() method of your activity or perhaps through binding to an orientation change event you could determine the current Orientation and update the background property of the layout.

```
protected void updateBackground()
{
    if(getRequestedOrientation() == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {                   
        //pseudo code
        setBackround(R.drawabl.background_landscape);
    }else{
        setBackround(R.drawabl.background_portrait);
    }
}
```